# Adding multiple columns to excel from TCL

Tags: excel, tcl

I'm trying to add multiple columns to excel from TCL. Here is the code

```
          set rows [array size atten]
          set columns { B}

          for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
            foreach column $columns {
              $cells Item $row $column $atten($row)
            }
          }
```

----This data is alone populated in excel

```
          set a_rows [array size transmit]
          set a_columns { C}

          for {set row 1} {$row <= $a_rows} {incr row} {
            foreach column $a_columns {
              $cells Item $row $column $transmit($row)
            }
          }
          $workbook SaveAs Filename {c:\tst.xls}
          $application Quit
```

Only the first array atten is populated in the excel file, it completely omits the part in the code that adds the transmit array in the excel file. How can this be solved?

Comment: What happens if you remove the first part of the code (dealing with that "atten" array? What happens if you add debug printouts in the second loop (`puts "$row, $column, $transmit($row)"`)--do you see expected and sensible values for *each* variable?

Comment: yes, when i remove the first part , it prints out the second loop..

Comment: What does "it prints out the second loop" stand for? Do you mean that if you remove/comment out the first loop the second loop works, that is, it fills a row of cells in the resulting document? Or what? Think through your answers otherwise we'll go round in circles.

Comment: yes if i remove/comment out the first loop the second loop works.. But i want both working..

Comment: OK, then I'm tempted to say that probably there's some code between these two blocks which interferes with the second loop.  For instance the `transmit` array gets unset (or its elements deleted) or something like this.  Use `puts` as suggested above and make sure that `$cells Item $row $column $transmit($row)` does really looks sensibly after all the variables are expanded.  A simple call to `puts "$cells Item $row $column $transmit($row)` before that invocation would be okay to test.

Comment: Maybe you get more answers if you explain the context. It seems you're using some kind of xls handling library, which one.

Answer (score 0):

Set both columns in a single foreach loop.